# Запрос на выборку left join hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Есть таблица `users` & `words` связь многие ко многим. И связующая таблица, ну например `users_words`(неожиданно, да?)
Как можно проделать при помощи `Criteria` такую выборку:

```
select * 
from words 
left join users_words on users_words.word_id = words.id
where users_words.user_id = {id} or 
      users_words.id is null'
```

Как я понимаю `hibernate` связывает через `inner join` но мне нужен `left`.

```
public class Group implements DomainModel{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_groups", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);
}

public class User implements DomainModel{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);
}
{
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Group.class);
    criteria.setFetchMode("users", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.createAlias("users","usersAlias");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("users.id"));
}
```

Comment: Тип объединения и его условия можно указать, как в методе `createCriteria()`, так и в `createAlias()`. Но лучше покажите классы сущностей, по ним проще будет.

Comment: Может я чего-то не улавливаю, но каким образом в m2m таблице может появится null?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, блин да согласен, никаким... Но по идее "верхний" запрос выведет все записи которые соответствую какому то юзеру или не соответствуют ни одному. Запрос подправлен но и старый вариант мне кажется работал бы так же

Comment: Правильно я понял, что надо выбрать те words, которые принадлежат отношению с определённым user и те, которые не принадлежат вообще никаким user?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Да, абсолютно верно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
List<Group> groups = session.createCriteria(Group.class, "g")
    .createAlias("users", "u", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
    .add(
        Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.eq("u.id", 1L),
            Restrictions.and(
                Restrictions.isEmpty("g.users"),
                Restrictions.isEmpty("u.groups")
            )
        )
    )
    .list();
```

Выбирает все группы, в которые никто не входит и которые никто не включает, а также группу, в которую входит пользователь с ID = 1.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что нужно!!!!