# как включить и обработать поля с null значениями в результат выполнения запроса через Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, null, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Имеется две таблицы Department и Employee со связью Many-to-One и One-to-Many. Хочу вывести результат в DTO, который бы содержал наименование департамента и количество сотрудников в нем. Сотрудники могут существовать только в департаментах. Департаменты без сотрудников существовать могут. Не могу понять как написать запрос с помощью Criteria чтобы в результат были включены так же и департаменты которые не содержат сотрудников. Т.е. чтобы строчка содержала имя департамента и количество сотрудников - 0.
Пробовал так:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Department.class, "dep")
            .createAlias("dep.employeesSet", "empl")
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("dep.id"), "id")
                    .add(Projections.property("dep.name"), "name")
                    .add(Projections.count("empl.id"), "quantity")
                    .add(Property.forName("dep.name").group(), "name"))
            .addOrder(Order.asc("quantity"))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(IndexPageView.class));
    indexPageViewList =  (ArrayList<IndexPageView>) crit.list();
```

В итоге в результат не включаются департаменты без сотрудников.

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name = "deapartment_id", updatable = true)
private Department department;

@Column(name = "age")
private String age;

@Column(name = "name", length = 25)
private String name;

public Employee() {
}

public Employee(Department department, String age, String name) {
    this.department = department;
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" +
            " id=" + id +
            ", name=" + name +
            ", age=" + age +
 " }\n";
 }
}
```

Department:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name", unique = false, updatable = true, length = 45)
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =    FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<Employee> employeesSet;

public Department() {
}

public Department(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Department(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<Employee> getEmployeesSet() {
    return employeesSet;
}

public void setEmployeesSet(Set<Employee> employeesSet) {
    this.employeesSet = employeesSet;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Department{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name=" + name + "}\n";
 }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class IndexPageView implements Serializable{

private int id;
private int quantity;
private String name;

public IndexPageView(){
}

public IndexPageView(int id, String name, int quantity){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "IndexPageView{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name=" + name +
            ", quantity=" + quantity + "}\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Возможно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653176/193183) вам что нибудь поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Victor, огромное спасибо что натолкнули на верный путь. Случай являет собой обычный LEFT JOIN. Нужный запрос у меня выглядит следующим образом:

```
 Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Department.class, "dep")
            .createAlias("employeesSet", "empl", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN )
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("dep.id"), "id")
                    .add(Projections.property("dep.name"), "name")
                    .add(Projections.count("empl.id"), "quantity")
                    .add(Property.forName("dep.name").group(), "name"))
            .addOrder(Order.asc("quantity"))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(IndexPageView.class));
    indexPageViewList =  (ArrayList<IndexPageView>) crit.list();
```